# Laravel/Eloquent - Order By a Model's Relationship Without Using Table Names

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a `Person` eloquent model that `belongsTo` an `Address`. My Laravel version is 4.2.5 and I am using PostgreSQL.

```
class Person extends Eloquent {
    public function address() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Address');
    }
}
```

My aim is to get a collection of `Person` resources that are sorted by the address_1 field of their related `Address` model.

I can accomplish this by referencing table names as show below, but I want to do it instead with Eloquent relationships, since I do not want to deal with tables for abstraction purposes.

```
Person::join('addresses', 'persons.id', '=', 'addresses.person_id')
    ->orderBy('address_1', 'asc')->get();
```

I have attempted the following Eloquent method without success.

```
Person::with('address')->whereHas('address', function($q)
    {
        $q->orderBy('address_1', 'asc');
    })->get();
```

This query fails with the error message:

```
Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column \"addresses.address_1\" must appear in the 
GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

In response to this, I tried adding this line above the `orderBy` statement which causes the query to succeed, but the ordering has no effect on the resulting `Person` collection.

```
$q->groupBy('address_1');
```

I would much appreciate a solution where I do not have to reference table names if it is possible. I have exhausted all resources on this subject, but surely this is a common use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$person = new Person;
$relation = $person->address();
$table = $relation->getRelated()->getTable();

$results = $person->join(

 $table, $relation->getQualifiedForeignKey(), '=', $relation->getQualifiedOtherKeyName()

)->orderBy($table.'.address_1', 'asc')
 ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, that spot on! I have used a dynamic version of your solution in a scope function which all of my models now inherit from.

Comment: Overly complex for what is needed. This can easily be achieved using Eager Load Constraints.

Comment: @Gaz 1st Have you read the question? 2nd No, it cannot be achieved using eager load constraints.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I did read the question and thought this would work but it doesn't. Unfortunately I can't remove the down vote unless you edit the answer.

Comment: @Gaz You can now, if you like.